# Problem with .NET web application using Powershell SDK

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I don't know what else to test hence my question here.

The goal is to continue using my Visual Studio project set to`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` and being able to obtain a Powershell session via the Powershell.SDK nuget package.

I noticed that running `"powerShell.Invoke()"` with a Visual studio project set to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` will give me a session as expected. However using **Sdk.Web** always returns an error => "An error occured that Powershell could not handle".

I even added a project reference to a console application in order to get the session working but the result is the same as explained above.

Am I doing something wrong or is there any workaround?

Could I change my .net web application to a console app and still host it on IIS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this by adding

```
<EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
```

and

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="6.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="6.0.4" />
```

to csproj file as stated here: [Issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14032)

Also I had to set the RuntimeIdentifier to win7-x64 in my publish profile:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my .NET core web api, running .NET 6.0. Updating to .NET 7.0, with its corresponding Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK at 7.3.4, solved the issue.